# Is there an mysql equivalent of postgresql $$any-text$$?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I get data from an MySql db, process them and then save them in 2 different db: Postgresql and Mysql.

No danger of sql injection. However, I need to protect some strings where I don't know what's inside. In Postgresql is super simple and using the $$ does the trick, but I can't find a way that is similarly simple in MySql.

Note: I build the query in php back-end, so it's something like:

```
INSERT INTO tabel (some_text, ... ) VALUES
($$some-text$$, 1, 2, 3),
($$other-text$$, 1, 2, 3),
....
($$more-text$$, 1, 2, 3)
```

Works in Postgresql, crushes in MySql.

Any suggestions?

L.E.:As requested, here is the initial select code:

```
 $sql = " SELECT
          ID_P,
          REPLACE(NAME_P,\"'\",\" \") AS NAME_P,
          date(DATE_P) AS DATE_P,
          countries_iso.MsCode AS Country_ISO3
        FROM " . $players_gender . "
          LEFT JOIN countries_iso ON countries_iso.Acronym = COUNTRY_P
        WHERE ID_P >" . $lastPlayer;
```

The problem comes from names that contain single quote. Here I replaced with space so I can move forward, but, of course, it is not a solution.
The result is processed and then inserted in Postgresql and in another table from MySql.

Comment: These are just "escaped" quotes. Escape your single quotes.

Comment: Already did it. Now I see the bugs and I'm looking for another solution. Bugs include displaying in front-end the \ char. Also searching by the "some'text" fails so it is inserted twice. I could eliminate it in the search but maybe I can find a more cleaner solution?
Or maybe I don't escape the quotes well?

Comment: See what bugs? What ` \ ` char? What frontend? Are you confusing what the debugger displays for some ` \ ` characters? `\n` *is* how most debuggers display a newline character. It's what most languages require if you want to enter a newline in a string too

Comment: Don't assume bugs in MySQL or Postgresql if something doesn't work in  the frontend.

Comment: What I did in php (in mysql select where I extract first the data):
    SELECT.... REPLACE(NAME_P,"'","\") AS NAME_P, ....
Then the name comes with the \ character inside. So when I search for it (like to check if I already inserted) it doesn't match. Also, in front-end was displayed with John O\'Doe.

Comment: Remove that `REPLACE` statement. You *added* an extra ` \ ` character in front of another character that doesn't need escaping since it's already in the output. It's not a *literal* with special characters, it's a return value. And you still haven't posted your actual code in the question

Comment: Posted the code. Well.. a part of it, if I paste all I used will be too much, I believe.

Comment: You haven't poste the PHP code. SQL queries don't care about the *contents* of columns. You don't need to replace `'` with anything. It doesn't need any kind of quoting. Which is why you can read this question too - SO doesn't perform quoting, it doesn't need to. Why does your *PHP* code choke when it finds a `'` in Name? Why did you put `REPLACE` in there?